# Why are subsets of compact sets not compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

So much of the properties of compact sets are motivated by finite sets, to the point that thinking of compact sets as topologically finite sets may yield some deeper understanding. But finite sets have the intuitive property that every subset of a finite set is also compact(also finite), why is it that compact sets give this up?

It is easy to state that they just do and provide the example $I=(0,1)$ and $K=[0,1]$ as an example, but the problem with that is it really only helps illuminate how compact sets work in the euclidean spaces. It isn't generally true in all spaces that open sets aren't compact, or that closed and bounded sets are compact. So there is a problem generalizing the ideas.

**The heart of my question is**: Given a subset $E$ of a compact set $K$ why isn't it compact?

**Simple Answer**: Because there is an open cover of $E$ which has no finite subcover

**The deeper question: Why?**

Comment: I would say that the question illustrates clearly why one shouldn't take the analogy between finite sets and compact sets too far. Finite sets are very very special compact sets. In particular, the phenomenon of accumulation points belonging to the set is lost entirely simply because a finite set has no accumulation points. Removing an accumulation point is enough to turn a compact set into a non-compact one, showing why one would not ever expect compact to be hereditary to all subsets.

Comment: It seems to me that compact sets are motivated by closed intervals, not by finite sets.  What are the serious applications of finite sets in analysis?

Comment: Why are subsets of compact sets not necessarily compact?  Because the definition of compactness allows counterexamples to exist.

Comment: I am not sure it is deep. All closed subsets of a compact set are compact (with appropriate separation axiom).

Comment: No need for a separation axiom there. Any closed subset of a compact set is compact, full stop.

Comment: "Why?"  The question isn't why, but how?  You can easily have an infinite subcover of $E$ that is not a subcover of $K$.  To extend $E$ to cover $K$ you must add open sets containing the missing points of $K$.  Now those *extra* open sets containing $K$ are *open* so they extend *past* just the missing points of $K$ and into the points of $E$.  And potentially elemenate the need for all the open sets covering $E$.  We can possibly do with less.  And because $K$ *is* compact these new open sets must do away with all but a finite number of the original ones covering $E$.

Comment: When we generalize some class of objects, we often focus on a subset of its properties that we want to study. So it's worth reflecting: which topological properties of finite sets are being generalized in the study of compact sets?

Comment: A corolary of definitions:  If $B \subset A$ where $A$ is compact and $B$ is not, and if $O$ is an infinite open cover of $B$ with no finite subcover.  ANd if $U$ is an open set so that $B\setminus A\subset U$; then $B\setminus U$ will be covered but a finite subset of the open cover $O$....  That might be a surprising counterintuitive result, but there is no reason our intuition should consider it false or paradoxical.

Comment: @fleablood Not really since $B-U= B\cap (X-U)$ and $X-U$ is closed by definition. So even without the set up we know that a closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: Actually the more I am thinking about it @fleablood you are right that is an interesting result. (ignore the last post it is somewhat wrong)

Comment: One weird way of looking at it is, I think, that there must be a compact set $K$ where $B-U=A-U \subset K \subsetneq B\subsetneq A$ where $A$ is compact.  $B$ is not.  $B\subset A$. And $U$ is an open set so that $B\setminus A \subset U$.  (Unless I made an error... I think it must be true.)

Comment: Respectfully, I would like to mention that every time during my education that I was consumed with a question such as this one, people couldn't wait to tell me that there was no "why" to be found. They never convinced me.

Comment: The "issue" is that topologies do not have a concept of size, other than cardinality. So a topological space can have a subspace that is in a vague since "bigger" than it. For example $[0,1]$ has a subspace that is homomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The real question here is: If finite sets are just the combinatorial analogue of compact spaces, why are arbitrary products of finite sets not always finite?

Comment: Isn't this analogous to asking why a subset of a closed line segment doesn't have to be closed?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft So much of the intuition derived from the idea of compactness comes from being an analogy to finite sets. The intuition behind closed sets is that their complement is open (ergo every point in the set should have all neighborhoods touching the set or else the complement wouldn't be open). Taking out points( or putting points in the complement) we could see how this might not be true. But for compact sets when looking for properties that generally hold for all topological spaces that help one get a grasp of how they look and work you are often told to look at how finite set---

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- behave but the problem is finite sets have the intuitive property that every subset of a finite set is compact. As a counterexample to this, you are usually pointed $(0,1)\subset [0,1]$, but the problem with that is not every space has a compact set that looks like $[0,1]$. $\mathbb{R}$ is a very nice space with very nice properties so it is possible that the intuition gained for why $(0,1)$ isn't compact won't carry over to looking at other spaces.  Students might ask well is it not compact because $(0,1)$ is open. No, is it not compact because it isn't closed. Not compact--

Comment: @CarlWitthoft because the space needs to be complete and $(0,1)$ needs to be closed no. THEN WHY ISN'T IT COMPACT. Would be the frustration. Checking whether a particular set is compact in an abstract topological space is difficult. Trying to reduce it down to particular more simple notions like openness or whether the space is complete is far easier than working with the definition of compactness. (which is useful when you know a set is compact or when you have generated a set that is compact.)

Comment: Side remark: if subsets of compact spaces are always compact, then every set in every topological space would be compact, because every topological space is a subset of its one-point compactification.

Comment: Please avoid subjective words in titles like "difficult, deep, interesting, hard". Make your title to the point and concise. Thanks,

Comment: @user160110 My analogy wasn't the best, to be sure. I appreciate all the comments in response -- they add a lot to the specifics of the discussion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One way to think of it is that compactness means that sequences (more generally, nets) cannot "run away". There are two types of "running away":

1. Running away to infinity (failure of the set to be bounded, or some analog*. Failure of the sequence/net to have any limit point at all).
2. Running away to a limit point which isn't in the set (failure of a set to be closed. The sequence/net has a limit point(s) in an ambient space, but that point is missing from the set in question).

If I have a compact space $X$, and I remove a point, $X-\{p\}$ may suddenly permit the second type of "running away".

At first it seemed awkward to me to phrase these things in terms of sequences and nets, because sequences and nets are "discrete" objects describing a continuous thing. But one can always phrase everything in terms of nets/filters of open sets, not of points. That can make it seem a bit more natural.

In any case, the basic point of a compact set is that it does not allow you to play a certain kind of game with infinity.

---

*For example, a uniform space is compact iff totally bounded and Cauchy complete, which are exactly analogous to conditions 1 and 2 above.

Comment: "running away" is cute.  +1

Comment: Your two types of running away are actually the same. You can add points to an ambient space providing limits for those "unbounded" sequences.

Comment: @PaulSinclair They can be unified, but I find sometimes refinement can be more enlightening than unification. (But why not both)

Comment: I don't see it as unifying disparate ideas, but recognizing that what you thought were disparate ideas were actually the same within the confines of area of discussion (in this case, topology). In the post, you talked about removing a point $p$ from $X$ permitting the second type of running away. But from a strictly topological viewpoint, "bounded" means "contained within a compact set", and removing $p$ results neighborhoods of $p$ becoming unbounded. It is only when non-topological concerns are considered that your two forms of running away become distinct.

Answer (score 33):

There's a nice symmetry/duality here stemming from the fact that "finite" has two generalizations in the topological category.

Images and subsets of finite sets are finite.

Discrete topological spaces generalize finite sets in that subspaces inherit the property.

Compact topological spaces generalize finite sets in that images inherit the property.

A topological space that is discrete and compact is finite.

Comment: Is there a way to define Discrete and Compact in that way somehow?

Comment: Does this answer the OPs question? Compact sets generalize the image property, but *why* don’t they satisfy the heredity property?

Comment: @SantanaAfton imagine you are a primitive human trying to develop a language, and your tribe is comprised of adult foragers. Because everyone is large and a human, you choose the single word "person" to describe a large human. However, you eventually need to distinguish between a baby and an adult, so you invent the notion of "size". Now an adult is a "large person" while a baby is a "small person". Then one day you are being attacked by a tiger and need a way to describe it to your tribe. There are no other tigers for a size comparison, and it is not human, so you are stumped...

Comment: ... so you invent the concept of "type", distinguishing between "humans" and "not-humans". Now you can say your tribe is comprised of "large humans", a baby is "small", and a tiger is "non-human". Though the tiger part of that analogy could be improved, this is exactly the situation at hand with finiteness. The notion of finiteness is quite natural, and so we defined it first, but eventually we came across structures that are akin enough to finiteness to share common properties but are quite distinct. With enough time, we boiled the main two properties down to compactness and discreteness.

Comment: It seems a bit inaccurate to describe “discrete” as a generalisation of “finite” to the topological category, since discrete spaces correspond to *arbitrary* sets, not just finite ones.

Comment: @PyRulez -- yes, I think so, at least if you are willing to think only about Hausdorff spaces. A Hausdorff space is compact if and only if it is an image of a limit of finite spaces, and a Hausdorff space is discrete if and only if it is a subobject of a colimit of finite spaces.

Answer (score 17):

What you may be after is the idea of a "pre-compact" subset, that is, a subset whose closure is compact. Then every subset of a pre-compact set is pre-compact; as are finite unions of them. A compact set is a closed pre-compact set.

For metric spaces, there is a closely connected concept of "totally bounded" subsets; a complete totally bounded set is compact.

Comment: This is not quite an answer to the question. Would have been better placed as a comment.

Answer (score 9):

Because a subset of a compact set is *smaller* than the compact set, the *sub*set might have a different open cover that does *not* cover the compact set.

This open cover may not have a finite subcover.

Example:  Let $A = [0,1]$ and $B = (0, 1] \subset A$.

Now $U = \{U_i| U_i= (\frac 1i, 1.1)\}$ is an open cover of $B$ but it is not an open cover of $A$.  (And $U$ does not have a finite subcovering of $A$.)

To extend $U$ so that that it will cover $A$ we must add an open set that contains $0$.  Call that $U_{\alpha}$ and $0 \in U_{\alpha}$ and now $U \cup \{U_{\alpha}\}$ is an open cover of $A$.

But $U_{\alpha}$ is open so there is an $r > 0$ so that $N_r(0) = (-r, r) \subset U_\alpha$.  But we can find an $n > \frac 1r$ or in other words $0 < \frac 1n < r$.

So $(0, \frac 1n] \subset U_{\alpha}$ so $(0, \frac 1n]$ is *covered* but the *single* open set $U_{\alpha}$.  *Without* $U_{\alpha}$ and with only $U = \{U_i = (\frac 1i, 1.1)\}$ we would have needed an infinite number of $U_i| i > n$ to cover $(0, \frac 1n]$.  But *with* $U_{\alpha}$ we don't need *ANY* of them anymore.

So ... throw them away!  We are left with $\{U_\alpha\} \cup \{U_i|i \le n; n > \frac 1r\}$ and that is a *finite* subcover of $A$.  And of $B$.

But the point is.  Without the *requirement* that there is an open set containing $0$ we wouldn't have a situation where a single open set must "do the work" of an infinite number of open sets which a non-compact set without the point $0$ could require.

... more explicitly with maybe too much detail...

So $A \setminus U_\alpha \subset (\frac 1n, 1]\subset B$.  And $(\frac 1n, 1]$ is covered by the finite subclass $\{U_i| i \le n\}$ and we don't *need* $\{U_i| i > n\}$  any more because $U_\alpha$ covers everything in $A$ that was not covered in $\{U_i|i > n\}$.

(Namely $U_{\alpha}$ covers $\{0\} \cup (0, \frac 1n]$ whereas *without* $U_\alpha$ we needed *ALL* of $\{U_i| i > n\}$ to cover $(0, \frac 1n]$)

So $\{U_i|i \le n\} \cup \{U_\alpha\} \subset U \cup \{U_\alpha\}$ *is* a finite subcover of $A$.  (even that $U$ had no finite subcover of $B$.

Comment: In my opinion, the fact that $0$ belongs to the set we are considering is the key of all. Namely, the behaviour and the effects a single neighborhood of $0$ has. I suppose it is related with the accumulation points of compact sets. Nice answer @fleablood.

Comment: That's exactly how I see it @Dog_69.  In terms of "compact" and and finite subcovers we don't have a good terminology for the points in $A\setminus B$ where $B$ is an non-compact subset... but in essence; the set $A\setminus B$ contain accumulation points of $B$ that aren't in $B$ and any open set containing $A\setminus B$ makes any infinite subcover of $B$ unnecessary.